# sublimetext - Multiple binding command

Tags: sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext

I'm a long time VS user, and I have gotten used to doing the following in order to comment out multiple lines of code:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Likewise, uncommenting requires this:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

Now I am switching to Sublime Text 3 for specific types of projects, and I would like to use the same bindings. I have transferred most bindings I commonly use, but I can't find a way to use the same "double" binding in Sublime. Is it possible?

And to be clear, of course I could un-learn the binding and use Sublime's, maybe even tweak VS to use that as well. However, I'd much rather use the one (ones?) I already know.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Preferences -> Key Bindings

You will have 2 view layouts

1. for Default key bindings that sublime provides.
2. for user defined key bindings

Click on the user defined layout (right side layout) and write following code into the file to make comment using `ctrl+k`

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+k"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } }
]
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants to have to press ctrl k followed by ctrl c, in which case the keys should be `["ctrl+k", "ctrl+c"]`

Comment: I am aware of how to do custom binds. My question is how to make it so you need to press both one after the other to trigger the command.

Comment: @Keith Hall Wouldn't that make it so that you can do either Ctrl-K or Ctrl-C to trigger the command (As opposed to doing both in sequence)?

Comment: Nope, to bind multiple separate key sequences to the same thing, you have to repeat the whole keybinding (command, args and context) - try it :)